# How to apply a jQuery extension to only certain elements in an html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am using the jQuery extension for searchable dropdowns found [here](http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/). It works great but I only want to apply it to some of the elements on my page, not all of them. Is there a way to pick and choose which selects it will modify?

This is how I'm using the script. I assume the answer has something to do with modifying that function, but I can't get it to work.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").searchable();
    });
```

Comment: modify your selector to target your specefic select element. `$("#myid").searchable();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a class?

```
<select class="searchable"><!-- content --></select>
```

And than the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select.searchable").searchable();
});
```

You can even invert the behavior if needed (but i wouldn't recommend):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // only select those without the searchable class
    $("select:not(.searchable)").searchable();
});
```

Comment: This is great. A class is definitely easier to use than the #id form.

Answer (score 3):

You need a more specific selector. `$("select")` will get all `<select>` tags. Use and id or class to be more specific:

```
$('#search').searchable();
```

See the [jQuery selectors documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors&redirect=no) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify to only use select elements in a certain div: `$('#div select').searchable();`